# Struggling to prove this identity using $(L_{-})^n$ operators

Tags: operators, angular-momentum, spherical-harmonics

I'm having difficulties proving the following identity using the lowering operators  $(L_{-})^n$ in the context of spherical harmonics:
$$
Y_{L}^{-M}(\theta, \phi)=(-1)^{M}Y^{*M}_{L}(\theta, \phi)
$$
I've attempted other strategies (like using $L_{+}$ instead), but I can't seem to arrive at a convincing proof. I appreciate any help or insights you can offer.

I think the main problem lies in deriving this identity: $(L_{-})^n Y_{L}^{M}(\theta,\phi)=e^{-in\phi}\sin^{n-M}\theta\frac{d^n\sin^{M}\theta Y_{L}^{M}(\theta,\phi)}{(d\cos\theta)^n}
$.

I know it is true, as I've proven it using mathematical induction, but I'm struggling to see how to derive it directly.

Thank you.

Comment: You can show this identity using the associated legendre polynomial form of the spherical harmonics. But do you want to do it just using the lowering operators?

Comment: Yes, I would like to try it using the lowering operators